# Keep ASP MVC FormCollection values after posting back from controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On my Index view, I need to allow the user to enter search criteria. This criteria is sent back to the Index controller in the form of a `FormCollection` object. I then extract the search criteria, pull the requested information from the database, and send the user back to the Index view. However, once the user get's back to the index view with the requested info, the data from the `FormCollection` object is now blank.

I would like to be able to keep the user's search criteria in the three text boxes that I use, however I'm not sure how using a `FormCollection`. Does anyone know either how to do this or another I should use?

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="searchBox" class="boxMe">
        <div id="zipBox" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; vertical-align: top;">
            @Html.Raw("Zip Code")
            @Html.TextArea("ZipSearch", new { style = "width: 300px;", placeholder = "Enter up to 35 comma separated zip codes" })
        </div>
        <div id="dateBox" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">
            @Html.Raw("Effective on this date")
            @Html.TextBox("DateSearch", null, new { style="width: 80px;"})
        </div>
        <div id="stateBox" style="float: left; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
            @Html.Raw("State")
            @Html.TextBox("StateSearch", null, new { style = "width: 25px;" })
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ViewResult Index(FormCollection searchDetails = null)
    {
        string zip = searchDetails["ZipSearch"];
        string date = searchDetails["DateSearch"];
        string state = searchDetails["StateSearch"];

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zip) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state))
        {
            return View();
        }

        string[] zipArray;
        DateTime effectiveDate;

        //Convert date string to DateTime type
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date))
        {
            effectiveDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            effectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        }

        //Conduct search based on Zip Codes
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zip))
        {
            //Create array and remove white spaces
            zipArray = zip.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < zipArray.Length; i++)
            {
                zipArray[i] = zipArray[i].Trim();
            }

            //Add zip codes to list object then send back to view
            List<ZipCodeTerritory> zips = new List<ZipCodeTerritory>();

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state))
            {
                foreach (var items in zipArray)
                {
                    var item = from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                               where z.ZipCode.Equals(items) &&
                                     z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                               select z;
                    zips.AddRange(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var items in zipArray)
                {
                    var item = from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                               where z.ZipCode.Equals(items) &&
                                     z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                               select z;
                    zips.AddRange(item);
                }
            }

            return View(zips);
        }

        //Zip code was not specified so search by state
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state))
        {
            var items = from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                        where z.StateCode.Equals(state) &&
                              z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                        select z;

            return View(items);
        }

        //Neither zip code or state specified, simply search by date
        var dateOnly = from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where z.EffectiveDate >= effectiveDate
                    select z;

        return View(dateOnly);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Following the instructions below I've created my View model like so:

```
public class ZipCodeIndex
{
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
    public string searchZip { get; set; }
    public string searchDate { get; set; }
    public string searchState { get; set; }
}
```

However in my View I cannot access any of these properties. The header for the view is written like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeIndex>
```

However all the `TextBoxFor` and the `TextAreaFor` helpers say none of the specified properties exist.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="searchBox" class="boxMe">
        <div id="zipBox" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; vertical-align: top;">
            @Html.Raw("Zip Code")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.searchZip, new { style = "width: 300px;", placeholder = "Enter up to 35 comma separated zip codes" })
        </div>
        <div id="dateBox" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">
            @Html.Raw("Effective on this date")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchDate, null, new { style="width: 80px;"})
        </div>
        <div id="stateBox" style="float: left; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
            @Html.Raw("State")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchState, null, new { style = "width: 25px;" })
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Missed that the page was looking for an `IEnuerable` Model object. Changed the header to this and fixed the problem.

```
@model Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeIndex
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into models and viewmodels instead of returning a form. I can give you some examples if its something you want to look into.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using a model and the DefaultModelBinder?

Comment: your ignoring the **M** in MVC

Comment: @RyanSchlueter: Yes, that would be appreciated. From what I'm gathering everyone is suggesting I create three search properties on the model (zip, state and date) and return these back to the view? If that's the case they would still have to be transferred between the incoming and outgoing model object, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the first thing you want to do is create a model just a new class file that looks something like this.

```
 public class AddressModel
    {    
        public int zip{ get; set; }
        public string state{ get; set; }
        public string date{ get; set; }      
    }
```

Then another new class file called a view model something like this. This way you can reference it for different things. Have like your search address then return the results in seperate list.

```
public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public AddressModel SearchAddress { get; set; }
        public List<AddressModel> ResultsAddress{ get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your view you reference the viewmodel like this `@model MVCTestProject.ViewModels.InsertPage`
on the top line.
Then these will be your text boxes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Insert", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchAddress.zip)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchAddress.state)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchAddress.date)
   <input id="button" name="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And in your controller it will be similar to this.

```
 public ActionResult Submit(AddressViewModel model)
        {
          model.ResultsAddress = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                        where z.StateCode.Equals(state) &&
                              z.EffectiveDate >= model.SearchAddress.date
                        select new AddressModel {
                        date = z.effectiveDate }).toList();
            return View("viewName", model);
        }
```

This will return your original Search criteria and the results. Is probably not all a hundred percent functional but the main ideas are there, and I can help you through problems if you decide to go down this path.

to display the results

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ResultsAddress.Count; i++)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ResultsAddress[i].date)
}
```

or for just displaying them top one can be used for editing and resubmitting the data.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ResultsAddress)
{
    <div>@item.date</div>
}
```

Comment: So I'm using the ViewModel to contain the search criteria, correct? On the Index page I need to display both the search criteria (View Model) and the results (Model). Is that possible using this method?

Comment: Ya the ViewModel holds both of them public AddressModel SearchAddress { get; set; }
        public List<AddressModel> ResultsAddress{ get; set; } Your search is the criteria and results is your results ill add to the solution how to display the results

Comment: Ah, got it. So the page is then set to display the View Model like you said. Ok, I'll give this a shot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Having some trouble accessing the properties of the view model. Edited the post to detail.

Comment: Have you tried taking the IEnumerable off and making it           @model Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeIndex

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Schlueter is right that you should use ASP.NET MVC principles such as model, autobinding to model fields in action parameters and so on. But the main in this case you should use strongly typed view:

Action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(ModelClass model)
{
    ....
    return("ViewName", model)
}
```

View:

```
@model SomeNamespace.ModelClass

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Insert", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property3)
   <input id="button" name="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I've edited the post to detail this method. For some reason, even though I've specified what View Model I need to use, I cannot get the Index page to recognize the View Model's properties. Any help would be appreciated. thx